# Erro ao mover Arquivo .rar de uma pasta para outra

Tags: java, arquivo-zip

Galera tenho um método que pega os arquivos que eu quero .rar de uma pasta e salva em outra, porém quando vou abrir o arquivo ele está corrompido.

```
try {
        //Origem
        File arquivoOrigem = new File(path);
        FileReader fis = new FileReader(arquivoOrigem);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fis);
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
        String line = "";
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            buffer.append(line).append("\n");
        }

        fis.close();
        bufferedReader.close();
        //Destino
        File arquivoDestino = new File(frmMenuInicial.caminhoTemporario+"/" + nomeArquivo + ".zip");
        System.err.println("TESTE: "+frmMenuInicial.caminhoTemporario+"/" + nomeArquivo +  ext);
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(arquivoDestino);
        writer.write(buffer.toString());
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Arquivo Salvo com Sucesso!\nPasta Destino: "+frmMenuInicial.caminhoTemporario, "Sucesso", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        //Process p;  
        //p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(path);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao tentar salvar Arquivo!\nVerifique se o Arquivo ainda exixte.\n"+e, "ERRO!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
```

Comment: Qual a versão do Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posso sugerir várias alternativas ao método que estás a usar.

1). Desde o Java 7 que podes utilizar o [NIO2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/copy.html) para copiar ficheiros.

2). Caso não possas utilizar essa versão (ou mais actual) podes ainda tentar usar a classe FileUtils que está disponível desde a versão 1.2 do apache commons-io library.

```
File source = new File("C:\\tempDir\\ficheiro1");
File dest = new File("C:\\tempDir\\ficheiro2");
try {
    FileUtils.copyDirectory(source, dest);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Em último recurso, caso queiras mesmo escrever a tua versão eu aconselharia

```
public static void copiarFicheiro(File sourceFile, File destinationFile) throws IOException {
    FileChannel inChannel = new FileInputStream(sourceFile).getChannel();
    FileChannel outChannel = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile).getChannel();
    try {
        // inChannel.transferTo(0, inChannel.size(), outChannel); 
        int maxCount = (64 * 1024 * 1024) - (32 * 1024);  --> Para ficheiros de tamanho superior a 64Mb
        long size = inChannel.size();
        long position = 0;
        while (position < size) {
            position += inChannel.transferTo(position, maxCount, outChannel);
        }
    } finally {
        if (inChannel != null) {
            inChannel.close();
        }
        if (outChannel != null) {
            outChannel.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Um comentário final para explicar o porquê do maxCount: No Windows, por vezes pode ocorrer um erro ao copiar ficheiros superiores a 64Mb, normalmente é lançada uma excepção do género: "Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service is thrown." 
Para evitar isto, é possível efectuar a copia do ficheiro num ciclo copiando apenas 64Mb de cada vez.

Comment: Muito Obrigado cara, usei a Classe FileUtils e funcionou perfeitamente.